# adding fluctuations to 5V

Tags: microcontroller, power, voltage, serial, dc

hobbyist here, hope someone can guide me.

I'm using I2C (only have 4 wires{PWR, GND, SDA, SCL}) to communicate with two exterior Circuit (Circuit A, and Circuit B, both have MCUs), which can be swapped between two locations (lets call them, left and right).

I need to identify which Circuit is in what location. I initially thought of using a voltage divider to lower left 5V to 4.9V and using an ADC on MCU to identify.

However, i now see this will melt my voltage divider as Circuit B draws 1.5 Amps, while the Circuit A draws 150mA.

Im now thinking if i can purposely add a fluctuation to my 5V DC PWR line, about 4.9V (between 5V to 4.8V) which my ADC could identify.

Can this be done with an OP-Amp? and if so, can you suggest the circuit.

If not, any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Might be easier to add an I2C switch to your master so that the two I2C branches are separate. This way, your master can direct to communicate only with A or B and discover which is which.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've actually simplified the problem a bit to prevent wall of text. It's actually 6 locations 3 per hand. I actually implement this for left and right, just need to figure out how to identify remaining 3 per hand.

Comment: How is it you know which power supply output wire is connected to which location, but you don't know which I2C wire is?

Comment: Why not use a shunt to detect how much power is being drawn from each side?

Comment: Sorry should have said Max power draw. Each circuit varies amount of current drawn. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Regarding The Photon's responce: sorry i don't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the following

- You have control over hardware and firmware of the sub-components A and B.
- Each location L and R has a connector (or a set of connectors), which provide: power, ground, connection to I<sup>2</sup>C

Then there are several options, which revolve around adding a location pin to the location's connector.  This pin can have a digital signal (low for Left, high for Right).  Or, it could have an analog voltage set by a fixed voltage divider (the voltage would be distinct at each location).

- A microcontroller (μC) in Circuit A (and B) can read its locating pin and choose its I<sup>2</sup>C slave address based on the location.
- A μC can have a fixed I<sup>2</sup>C slave address.  The slave would report the value of its locating pin during system initialization.  Then the software on the master would take care of routing the messages.

Comment: Much appreciated for the response.

Comment: You are correct, i have control over hardware and firmware, but i can not add any additional connectors, pins, or wires, to link the circuits (physical design limitation). However, i can do whatever to the 4 existing connectors, hence the original thoughts of slight voltage decrease (voltage divider) and now adding voltage fluctuation.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think injecting a signal onto the power is such a great idea. Power always has low impedance at AC, so you will have to drive it very hard to make much of a voltage swing.

How about this: have the exterior circuits drive SDA to a specific voltage for some period of time after connection (could be divider or op-amp). The MCU board can read SDA with an ADC. After some time period, you can disconnect the drive voltage and let SDA be controlled as usual. Another way to handle it would be to drive SDA to a specific voltage until SCL toggles a certain number of times, then disconnect the drive. This has the advantage that the MCU is totally in control of the timing.

There are a lot of slight variations on the idea of using SDA for out-of-band signalling. Let me know if you want to hear other ideas or more detail.